# FBAudienceNetwork interstitial ads displayed upside down when orientation is landscape right

Tags: ios, facebook, orientation, interstitial

On landscape left it is fine but when I rotate the device as landscape right, advertisements mostly displayed upside down (behaves like device orientation is landscape left).

I tried both 4.25.0 and 4.26.0 FBAudienceNetwork SDK versions.
And devices: iPhone 5 (iOS 10.3.3), iPod touch 5 (iOS 9.3.5)

I also tried the sample project on https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network and it behaves same.

When I search about the issue I faced, could not see any other people complains about it.

Is there such problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It works fine with version 4.24.0. I hope they fix it with the new version.